# Issues with Postgis 2.2.0 and Postgres 9.4.5: PG::UndefinedFile - ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.1"

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.4, rgeo

I, unfortunately, upgraded to postgis to 2.2.0 via homebrew and am now getting the errors below. I would go back to 2.1.0 but the formula doesn't seem to be available anymore. Going to 2.0 tries to downgrade Postgres to 9.2.

Any thoughts on what else could I try would be much appreciated?

Versions:

- PostGres: 9.4.5_2
- Postgis: 2.2.0
- activerecord_postgis_adapter: 3.1.0
- pg gem: 0.18

Errors below:

```
PG::UndefinedFile - ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.1": No such file or directory
:
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:596:in `block in exec_no_cache'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:596:in `exec_no_cache'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:588:in `execute_and_clear'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:160:in `exec_query'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:737:in `column_definitions'
  activerecord-postgis-adapter (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgis/schema_statements.rb:9:in `columns'
```

Basic Debugging:

```
$ pg_config --pkglibdir                                        
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5/lib

$ ls -lrt /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5/lib/postgis
postgis-2.1.so*
```

/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/ still shows folders for 9.4.5_1 and 9.4.5_2. I have also tried dropping, creating and altering the postgis extension on Postgres and that runs without hiccups. When I look for installed extensions:

```
-[ RECORD 36 ]----+---------------------------------------------------------------------
name              | postgis
default_version   | 2.1.7
installed_version | 2.2.0
comment           | PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions
```

Comment: [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/) (9.4.5) bundles PostGIS (2.1.8) and Just Works™. I must admit I abandoned installing Postgres myself when I had to start dealing with PostGIS too. Looks like they've got 9.5beta2/2.2.0 if you still want to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, running `ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;` from the postgres shell seemed to do the trick:

```
$ \dx  postgis                
| 2.1.7   | public     | PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions
$ ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE; 
ALTER EXTENSION

$ \dx postgis                
| 2.2.0   | public     | PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions
```

After that, the error was gone

Answer (score 1):

On OSX with homebrew, I generally update both `postgresql` and `postgis` together as follows:

```
brew update
brew uninstall postgis
brew upgrade postgresql
brew install postgis

# update the postgis extension 
psql -d your_database -c "alter extension postgis update"

# recompile the native extensions in the pg gem
gem pristine pg
```

If you are doing a major PostgreSQL update (for example, from 9.4 to 9.5) and want to preserve your data, first look into `pg_upgrade`.